# Why Spring gives priority to 405 Http Error over 406 Http Error

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, spring-mvc

I have a rest Controller in Spring **3.1** which allows GET and POST methods.

The POST method is restricted to the producing outputs with the mapping

@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json"})

if I POST the next request it returns a 405 Error with "Allow: GET" Header.

```
POST /resources/projects
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: text/html
```

I have found that Spring MVC Framework gives priority to 405 Error in RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java in the handleNoMatch method.

```
protected HandlerMethod handleNoMatch(Set<RequestMappingInfo> requestMappingInfos, String lookupPath, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
....
....
    if (!allowedMethods.isEmpty()) {
        throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(request.getMethod(), allowedMethods);
    }
    else if (!consumableMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
        MediaType contentType = null;
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContentType())) {
            contentType = MediaType.parseMediaType(request.getContentType());
        }
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException(contentType, new ArrayList<MediaType>(consumableMediaTypes));
    }
    else if (!producibleMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(new ArrayList<MediaType>(producibleMediaTypes));
    }
```

But I want my REST API to give priority to the 406 Error, as it is what makes sense, am I right with my priority? How could I achieve that?

I know this issue is resolved in Spring 3.2 but I can't upgrade to 3.2.

I've been suggested to extend RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you post the full response statement and any log statements that Spring might have produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with this issue again today, I have a proper answer on **how to add a custom Handler Mapping to Spring to solve the problem.**

This issue is not happening in Spring 3.2 as @Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out.

If you want to solve it in Spring 3.1 you can:

1. subclass the HandlerMapping as you can see here:

{

```
public class CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

protected HandlerMethod handleNoMatch(
        Set<RequestMappingInfo> requestMappingInfos, String lookupPath,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    Set<String> allowedMethods = new HashSet<String>(6);
    Set<MediaType> consumableMediaTypes = new HashSet<MediaType>();
    Set<MediaType> producibleMediaTypes = new HashSet<MediaType>();
    for (RequestMappingInfo info : requestMappingInfos) {
        if (info.getPatternsCondition().getMatchingCondition(request) != null) {
            if (info.getMethodsCondition().getMatchingCondition(request) == null) {
                for (RequestMethod method : info.getMethodsCondition()
                        .getMethods()) {
                    allowedMethods.add(method.name());
                }
            }
            if (info.getConsumesCondition().getMatchingCondition(request) == null) {
                consumableMediaTypes.addAll(info.getConsumesCondition()
                        .getConsumableMediaTypes());
            }
            if (info.getProducesCondition().getMatchingCondition(request) == null) {
                producibleMediaTypes.addAll(info.getProducesCondition()
                        .getProducibleMediaTypes());
            }
        }
    }
    if (!producibleMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(
                new ArrayList<MediaType>(producibleMediaTypes));
    } else if (!consumableMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
        MediaType contentType = null;
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContentType())) {
            contentType = MediaType
                    .parseMediaType(request.getContentType());
        }
        throw new HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException(contentType,
                new ArrayList<MediaType>(consumableMediaTypes));
    } else if (!allowedMethods.isEmpty()) {
        throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(
                request.getMethod(), allowedMethods);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

And then you have 2 options:
2.1 Add this bean to your Spring XML Configuration.

```
<bean name="handlerMapping" class="com.ncr.mobile.rest.handler.CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="-1" />
</bean>
```

2.2 Add this method to you WebConfig. The order works to give the max priority to the class.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
          RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping();
          handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
          handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
          return handlerMapping;
  }

}
```

I hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've incorrectly configured your application. Either the `@RequestMapping` isn't as you've shown it, or it's annotating a method in a `@Controller` that isn't being registered.

With the following being the only mapping registered with my `DispatcherServlet`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
public String home() {
    System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
    return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}
```

and tested with

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/resources/projects");
post.setHeader("Context-type", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Accept", "text/html");
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
System.out.println(httpResponse);
```

I get

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable [Server: [...]]
```

as expected.

You should double check your logs to see if the handler method you want is actually being registered. The logs will show something like

```
2013-11-30 01:30:33,958 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/projects],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String xyz.spring.mvc.HomeController.home()
```

**After your comment and the changes you suggested**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
public String home() {
    System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
    return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeGet() {
    System.out.println("HomeControllerGet: Passing through...");
    return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}
```

here are the startup logs

```
2013-12-02 08:33:57,233 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/projects],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String xyz.sample.baremvc.HomeController.home() 
2013-12-02 08:33:57,234 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/projects],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String xyz.sample.baremvc.HomeController.homeGet()
```

Tomcat still gives me a 406

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable [[...]]
```

which makes sense. Remember that the javadoc for the `produces` attribute states

> The format is a single media type or a sequence of media types, **with a
>   request only mapped if the Accept matches one of these media types.**

Since your request has an `Accept` header that doesn't match the media type, the request is not acceptable and a 406 will occur.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote PUT instead of POST.

Comment: @Chexpir Take a look at my edit. I think you have a configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking all the time to test it. As I've said: _I have a rest Controller in Spring which allows GET and POST methods._ so You should add for your test another method in the controller with the next mapping to test it right.

@RequestMapping(value = "projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeGet() {
    System.out.println("HomeControllerGet: Passing through...");
    return "WEB-INF/views/home.jsp";
}

Comment: @Chexpir You're welcome. I took another stab at it by adding the other handler, I still get the same expected behavior. Can you check if there's anything else you aren't showing us?

Comment: Thank you. Both of them are registered, but i am still getting a 405 error.
15:36:48.355 [WGBAL185127-8ZP] [main] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping -

Mapped "{[/resources/projects],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}"
...
Mapped "{[/resources/projects],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<.....project.model.ProjectFacade>

This are the only 2 methods allowed for this endpoint. I am using Spring 3.1.0

Comment: @Chexpir I'll have to check when I get home, but I was on Spring 3.2.5.

Comment: Thank you, I should give you all my reputation for all the time you are spending on this!

Comment: @Chexpir So, yes, it is a version issue. If you can switch, do so. If not, you'd have to make some pretty major changes that I don't think are worth it.

Comment: I can't. I checked on a meeting and we have legacy 3.0 and 3.1 code that don't want to risk any incompatibility issue with 3.2.Thank you!

Comment: @Chexpir What do you mean by `grap me`?

Comment: Sorry the typo. If you tell me about the major changes in case of Spring 3.1, I'll give the accepted answer to you :-)

Comment: @Chexpir [Here's a very detailed change log.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/changelog.txt)

Comment: I was refering to your previous phrase: "If not, you'd have to make some pretty major changes that I don't think are worth it". I was asking for the major changes. Do I have to subclass RequestMappingHandlerMapping or something like that?

Comment: @chexpir Ooo, sorry, still early. Yes, you would have to subclass it like Lawrence says in their answer. But you would also have to register it which clashes with the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableWebMvc` configurations. You would basically have to do all that configuration yourself. I don't know all of them off the top of my head. They should be documented in the Spring MVC documentation under special beans or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you subclass RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping or RequestMappingHandlerMapping?

Comment: Could I? This class is a Spring internal class, called also from internal classes. I don't know if this kind of things are possible. If they are, welcome them if somebody can explain me how to do it!